# Store Pointer Property array/list

Tags: python

How can i store a array/list of Pointer Properties?!
I want every pointer to point to a object and get a specific pointer with an index or key.

```
import bpy

class customPropertiesGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    objects = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)    
bpy.utils.register_class(customPropertiesGroup)

bpy.types.Object.customList = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=customPropertiesGroup)


ob = bpy.context.active_object.customList.add().name = 'ob_01'
ob = bpy.context.selected_objects[1].copy()
```

is how can i access ob_01 and does ob_01 actually store a copy of selected object [1]?

Comment: Python does not use pointers the way C does. http://qa.geeksforgeeks.org/1540/qa.geeksforgeeks.org/1540/does-python-support-pointers-like-c.html

Comment: @JustinHelps sure but im talking about https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.PointerProperty.html they exist and i want a array of these props that is unique to every object when i make a array of the pointerprops and store them in a object they are shared between all objects

Comment: Okay, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. Could you add some code that you would think should work but doesn't?

Comment: @JustinHelps my current workaround is that i create new objects and just dont add them to the scene/renderlayer/collection so that they remain hidden, they all have a index prop and when i want to access one object i loop trough all objects that have a pointer prop if that equals to the active object i check their index props if that index prop is what i want then i have my reference to the object  that i want to access having a single array/list variable would be much cleaner but if thats not possible i will just use my messy system

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Can add methods to the propertygroup definition**

Something that is very handy IMO is the ability to add methods to the property group.

Here I've added `copy` to make a copy of itself to the collection, and `add` to add an object to the collection. In both cases the object name is used as the collection item name.

Remember that 2.8 uses annotations for properties.

```
import bpy

class ObjectCopy(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    object: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)    

    def copy(self):
        self.object = self.id_data.copy()
        self.name = self.object.name
        return self.object

    def add(self, ob):
        self.object = ob
        self.name = ob.name
        return self.object

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectCopy)
    bpy.types.Object.copies = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=ObjectCopy)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectCopy)
    del(bpy.types.Object.copies)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Some testing in the python console.

```
>>> C.object.copies.clear()
>>> for o in C.selected_objects:
...     C.object.copies.add().add(o)
...     
bpy.data.objects['Cube.002']
bpy.data.objects['Cube.001']
bpy.data.objects['Cube']

>>> C.object.copies.add().copy()
bpy.data.objects['Cube.005']

>>> C.object.copies['Cube'].object
bpy.data.objects['Cube']
```

Comment: nice thank you is there a way to store only bpy.context.active_object.data or modifiers?

Comment: For data could add pointers for each case, eg mesh, armature.  Possibly easiest to do both on an object level. Save a dummy object, and hence it's data and any added modifiers.

Answer (score 3):

You are actually pretty close.

```
class CustomProp(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    id: bpy.props.IntProperty()
    object: bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        name="Object",
        type=bpy.types.Object,
    )

bpy.types.Scene.custom = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=CustomProp)
```

Adding objects:

```
scn = bpy.context.scene
item = scn.custom.add()
item.id = len(scn.custom)
item.object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="My Object", object_data=C.object.data)
item.name = item.object.name
```

Comment: i get this error: TypeError: bpy_struct.__new__(type): expected a single argument, im using 2.80 0bbff8a71138