# Store object for operator

Tags: python

I have a simple operator that works with the active object and another one in the scene. When the operator is opened again I want to access both objects again.

Accessing the active object is no problem, but how to store the other object for the operator, what is the best way?

Scene properties? Then I would need to store a dictonairy with the active object as key and the other object as value, is this possible or is there a better way to do this?

Thx!

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134996/store-pointer-property-array-list